# Vue.js: How to reset dynamic form changes

Tags: javascript, arrays, forms, vue.js, vuejs2

I have like this template currently:

```
<div>
    <div v-for="(item, key) in items" :key="key">
        <div>
            <input type="text" :value="item.title">
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" :value="item.description">
        </div>
        <div class="actions">
            <button type="button" @click="discardChanges(item)" :disabled="!itemChanged">Discard changes</button>
            <button type="button" @click="sendChanges(item)" :disabled="!itemChanged">Save</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                itemChanged: false,
                items: [
                    {
                        title: "Apple",
                        description: "The bigger company of the world"
                    },
                    {
                        title: "Amazon",
                        description: "The bigger online store of the USA"
                    },
                ]
            }
        },
        methods: {
            sendChanges(item) {
                // Send API request to update item
            },
            discardChanges(item) {
                // Set old value if item changed
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

In this case I generate dynamic `inputs` from array of items. I need to correctly control my action `buttons` by detecting **current item** changes.

For example user will change second item title and will click to `Discard changes` button. In this case how I can set old value to input?

Also how I can correctly `disable` or `enable` action buttons by comparing ch

Comment: your need a clone of the original data, then simply set it back on discard `mounted(){this.items_orig = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.items))}` - `discardChanges(){this.items = this.items_orig}`, if you want stepped undo, then your need a stack/array of changes

Answer (score 1):

I have made use of another array called oldValues and modified the methods accordingly. Also I suggest you to use v-model instead of :value

```
<div>
    <div v-for="(item, key) in items" :key="key">
        <div>
            <input type="text" v-model="item.title">
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" v-model="item.description">
        </div>
        <div class="actions">
            <button type="button" @click="discardChanges(key)" :disabled="!itemChanged">Discard changes</button>
            <button type="button" @click="sendChanges(item, key)" :disabled="!itemChanged">Save</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                itemChanged: false,
                oldValues: [
                    {
                        title: "Apple",
                        description: "The bigger company of the world"
                    },
                    {
                        title: "Amazon",
                        description: "The bigger online store of the USA"
                    },
                ],
                items: [
                    {
                        title: "Apple",
                        description: "The bigger company of the world"
                    },
                    {
                        title: "Amazon",
                        description: "The bigger online store of the USA"
                    },
                ]
            }
        },
        methods: {
            sendChanges(item) {
                // Send API request to update item
              this.oldValues[key]=item;
            },
            discardChanges(item) {
                // Set old value if item changed
               this.items[key]=this.oldValues[key];
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```